# Unable to delete Azure Function Keys in staging Deployment Slot?

Tags: azure-functions, key, azure-deployment-slots

I have an Azure Function that uses `prod` and `staging` Deployment Slots. I was able to delete some Function Keys from the `prod` slot, but when I try to delete the same Function Keys in the `staging` slot, I get the error "Failed to delete ".

The same issue is now occurring when I want to **create** a new Function Key.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried stopping the function, still no go.

How do I delete a Function Key for a Function using a Deployment Slot?

Answer (score 1):

2 Slots of my function App contains 2 function keys each (1 default created key and 1 custom function key created manually in both the slots with same key-value):

**Production Slot**:

[image]

**Staging Slot**:

[image]

**Deleting the Function Keys**

**From Prod Slot**:
[image]

**From Staging slot**:

[image]

For the above scenario, the traffic of prod slot is 100% and Staging slot is 0% in the Deployment Slots.

I think the cause might be your staging slot is having any traffic coming from staging slot functions. If yes, make the traffic to `0%` and try deleting your function keys.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing with CREATING Function keys in staging deployment slots that have 0% traffic.